# Comparing Windows and Linux machine hardware

Tags: linux, process, hard-disk, cpu, oracle-linux

I have to compare Linux and Windows machine hardware?
In windows system, I can open the My computer properties and see the details like processors, RAM Hard disks etc.
Through task manager, I can see how many processors are there ?
In the same way, Linux has commands to do that like
`cat /proc/meminfo
cat /proc/cpuinfo`

How to check hard disk types and number of processors in my linux machine?

Comment: Do you have three questions or are there two spurious question marks in there? What are the Linux distributions you are using?

Comment: BTW You can use `systeminfo` on Windows to get the processor and memory info, in a similar way to Linux. No need to wade through layers of menus with the mouse.

Comment: @Anthon: I am using Oracle Linux.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know exactly which distro you need. But in Ubuntu you seek for **Details** in Dashboard and you'll find your CPU (with amount of logical processors & clock rate per physical core), GPU (only the name, not the memory) and amount of RAM.

So far for rest, I don't know.

onesysadmin (on ServerFault), says:

`$ cat /proc/cpuinfo` for CPU

```
$ free
$ cat /proc/meminfo
```

for RAM

Comment: I am using Oracle Linux. What is new in your answer? I have already explained what I did and you also just copied what I written.